# TP4056 Heating While in Use

Tags: lipo

I am trying to charge a 3.7v 200mah 10c E-Cig battery with a 3.7v 380mah 25c Li-Po battery and a TP4056. For some reason my TP4056 is burning up when connected to the 380mah battery. I did some research and calculated that using a 15k resistor would get me around my target output of .24 amps to charge the E-Cig battery. Would this be correct and if so, would it help cool down my TP4056?

Comment: What does your TP4056 module data sheet say it needs as input voltage? These things are normally designed to run from 5V, not 3.7V. In any case, you need more than 3.7V to charge a 3.7V battery.

Comment: Ahhhh, the data sheet says it needs a minimum supply voltage of 4v. So if i change my battery to a 5v would it solve this issue?

Comment: Draw a schematic.

Comment: Reverse polarity? Too much nicotine?

Answer (score 1):

The TP4056 is a complete constant-current/constant-voltage linear charger for single cell  lithium-ion batteries.

This means it can charge up to the input voltage or 4.2V whichever is smaller.

But Vin is rated at 4V min which is still ok for LiPo charging.

But using a lower supply like 3.7V means the internal FET does not have as low a Ron switch resistance so I^2Ron power will make it hotter.

However my [**specs**](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) indicate 15k will not suit 0.24A rather only <130mA ( off scale)

5k for 250mA should be ok.